# How to configure PROMPT such that CMD commands begin from the next new line?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, prompt

My current `cmd` looks like :

[image: this]

For this I did something like :

```
setx PROMPT $c$$$f-$g$s
```

But I want something like :

> $ (MY CURRENT PATH <--> DATE) : *Nothing here/ Blank*
>
> ($) ->  *Command Goes here ...*

I tried :

```
setx PROMPT $$$s$c$p$s$l--$g$d$f$s:^
more? $c$$$f-$g$s
```

But sadly it didn't work. Is it even possible to do this?

Please do not suggest using other terminals like babun, git, bash on windows, hyper etc. I already am using all of these :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

```
 PROMPT /?
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
```

...

> But I want something like :
>
> ```
> $ (MY CURRENT PATH <--> DATE) : Nothing here/ Blank
> ($) -> Command Goes here ...
> ```

```
prompt $$ $C$P $L--$G $D$F$_$C$$$F -$G
```

produces:

```
$ (C:\Windows\Temp <--> 2017-08-03)
($) -> █
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir ! I didn't know about the `$_` part. Helped a lot :) I was trying to get this result for about an hour.